# Função BDMédia Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Se eu executar a função BDMédia em uma coluna da tabela que contém texto, ele vai entrar como contagem na média?

Por exemplo, em uma coluna com 10 dados, sendo 9 números e 1 texto, ele vai dividir a soma dos valores por 9 ou por 10?

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi certo, para que funcione a formula BDmedia, na coluna de valores ele vai fazer a media conforme o criterio dos filtros =BDMédia(banco_de_dados; campo; critérios) "criterios", se um exemplo voce determina os filtros, mas nos campos de valores estiver algum texto provavelmente a formula vai dar erro no calculo;

Answer (score 0):

A função `BDMÉDIA` tem os seguintes parâmetros:

```
                       `BDMÉDIA(banco de dados, campo, critérios)`
```

- No parâmetro `banco de dados`, a primeira linha possui os rótulos das
  suas colunas.
- O parâmetro `campo` trata da posição da coluna no banco de dados
  inteiro por nome do rótulo ou por número da coluna.
- Por sua vez, o parâmetro `critério` é onde o usuário pode criar
  qualquer intervalo de argumento, desde que denomine um rótulo de
  coluna e uma célula abaixo dele como condição.

Assim, se algum texto estiver escrito em uma coluna com valores numéricos, a combinação de uma função `SE` com a função `ÉTEXTO` solucionaria seu problema.